# Finding specific object after another one

Tags: python-3.x, list, extract

I am creating a program that extracts the relevant information from a textfile with 500k lines.

What I've managed so far is to take the info from the textfile and make it into a list which each element being a line.

The relevant text is formatted like this:

```
*A title that informs that the following section will have the data I'm trying to extract *

*Valuable info in random amount of lines*

*-------------------*
```

and in between each relevant section of information, formatted in the same way but starting with another title i.e:

```
*A title that shows that this is data I don't want *

*Non-valuable info in random amount of lines *

*------------------- *
```

I've managed to list the indexes of the starting point with the follow code:

```
start = [i for i, x in enumerate(lines) if x[0:4] == searchObject1 and x[5:8] == searchObject2]
```

But I'm struggling to find the stopping points. I can't use the same method used when finding the starting points because the stopping line appears also after non-important info.

I'm quite the newbie to both Python and programming so the solution might be obvious.

Comment: What output format do you want? A list containing pairs of indices `(<start>,<stop>)`? A list of strings containing the lines of valuable data?

Comment: Hello! Prefered output format is a list of strings containing the lines of valuable data, but I'm open to other suggestions if that is not possible.

Comment: Can you please paste real input sample and expected output? This will be a lot better to understand you problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to loop over the input file line by line, and keep only valuable lines. To know whether a line is valuable, we use a boolean variable that is:

- set to true ("keep the lines") whenever we encounter a title marking the beginning of a section of interesting data,
- set to false ("discard the lines") whenever we encounter an end of section mark. *The variable is set to discard even when we encounter the end of a useless section, which doesn't change its state.*

Here is the code (`lines` is the list of strings containing the data to parse):

```
bool keep = false;
data = []

for line in lines:
    if line == <title of useful section> # Adapt
        keep = true
    elif line == <end of section> # Adapt
        keep = false
    else:
        if keep:
            data.append(line)
```

If none of the cases matched, the line was one of two things:

- a line of data in a useless section
- the title of a useless section

So it can be discarded.

Note that the titles and end of section lines are not saved.

Comment: Works! Thanks alot!